# Total doesn't include tax

Tags: totals

The total price doesn't include the tax price.
I tried to change the tax settings in admin->stores->configuration->sales->tax.
But it's not working.

[image]

[image]

I checked the totals data.
The currency is same for base_grand_total and grand_total.
Please let me know why they are diffent.

Comment: what is the product tax class? also, how do the tax rules look like?

Comment: product class must be taxable good

Answer (score 0):

You should activate **Include Tax In Order Total**

Below is the step:

> Admin -> Stores -> Configuratuion -> Sales -> Tax -> Shopping Cart Display Settings -> Include Tax In Order Total

Make it   **Yes**

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean